# How to detect a empty spot when using a scanner and fill it in with a predetermined answer? (Java)

Tags: java

Currently I am writing a program that pulls data from a file. There are normally 2 numbers on a line in the file in which the first one represents a temperature and the second on represents the wind speed. I set it up so a scanner reads the file but there are some places where the wind speed is blank. Since there are blank spaces it ends up just skipping over the spot and going to the next number that it sees. Is there anything that I could add that would make it so if there is a blank spot puts an NA or 0 in? I am pretty new to java so I am very confused.

An example of the data file:

```
20\s\s\s10\n
15\s\s\s 5\n
12\s\s\s\n 
 5\s\s\s16\n
```

```
public class readingData {


    private Scanner x;



    public void openFile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("weatherData.txt"));

    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("File not found");
    }
  }

  public void readData(){
       while(x.hasNext()) {

            int tempf = x.nextInt();
            int windspeed = x.nextInt();



            int celsius = ((tempf-32)*5/9); //Celcius equatin
            double windmps = windspeed / 2.23694; // Wind in mps equation
            double windchill = 35.74 + 0.6215*tempf + (0.4275*tempf - 35.75) * Math.pow(windspeed, 0.16); // Windchill equation 
            double windchillc = ((windchill-32)*5/9);

            if (tempf <= 50) {
               System.out.printf("%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s\n", "Farenheit:","Celcius","Wind Speed(MPH)" ,"Wind Chill(F)" , "Wind Chill(C)" , "Wind Speed(MPS)");
               System.out.printf("%20s%20s%20s%20s%20s\n", tempf, celsius,windspeed ,(int)windchill, (int)windchillc, (int)windmps);



            }     
       }

    }

    public void closeFile() {
       x.close(); 
    }


}
```

Comment: Your file example is not very relevant since it doesn't contain any occurrence of the edge case you're mentioning.

Comment: @Dici Sorry! Just updated it so it has what I am mentioning.

Comment: It would be useful to indicate blank characters somehow on the example. For example, is there always a single space between the two numbers? When a number is missing, is it replaced with a blank character or just with nothing?

Comment: @Dici There's always 3 blank characters in between the two numbers and when there isn't a number there, it automatically moves to the next number which messes up the rest of the program.

Comment: No I'm only talking about the format of the file. Answers will depend on the guarantees you have about the format. For example, is it `12\s\s\s\n` or `12\s\s\s\s\n` for the line what doesn't have wind speed (if we represent spaces using `\s`)?

Comment: @itsDathan - Any update? I hope the solution worked for you. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thank you so much! One question I do have is now when I run it, all of the temperatures come back as Not Valid or 0. It may be a problem on my end but i'm going to attempt to fix it now!

Comment: @itsDathan - I've updated my answer to print the temperature and wind speed data read from the file. I've also posted the content of my file. It seems there is some other issue with your file/code. I recommend you copy and run my program and data and then check your code/data. Feel free to comment in case of any issue/doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing the problem because you are reading using `nextInt()`. I recommend you read a line using `nextLine()` and then split it using regex e.g.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int tempf, windspeed;
        Scanner x;
        try {
            x = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
            while (x.hasNextLine()) {
                String[] data = x.nextLine().split("\\s+"); // Split the line on space(s)
                try {
                    tempf = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
                    System.out.print(tempf + " ");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid/No data for temperature");
                    tempf = 0;
                }
                try {
                    windspeed = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
                    System.out.println(windspeed);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid/No data for wind speed");
                    windspeed = 0;
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to read file.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
20 10
15 5
12 Invalid/No data for wind speed
5 16
```

**Content of file.txt:**

```
20    10
15    5
12 
5     16
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.